# Local relative path

Tags: html, css, relative-path

I´m working in a local project (offline) and need show a txt file outside of directory of html. How implement the relative path?

```
main-app
|
|-core-app
|
|-logs
|   |-log-file.txt
|
|-plugin
    |-plugin-core
    |-www
       |-index.html
```

The file is on **logs** folder, I need show it in index.html. I try to use ***src="../../../logs/log-file.txt"*** but don't work. An example of the code in html:

```
<object type="text/plain" data="../../../logs/log-file.txt"></object>
```

Comment: relative is allways relative to the root folder, so
`/logs/log-file.txt` should work.

Comment: In the **plugin** folder have a plugin that run a webserver for html, the root of this webserver is the directory **WWW**. So, I need load the file inside the logs folder.

I read in some site that in html, relative paths only works at level 2, in local files. Above this, only in webservers. This true?

Comment: if the webserver is at the `www` directory, you cannot access the logs directory since it is outside the web root.. you will need to do it with server side code, get the code into a variable, and print it on the html or inside the `data`.

Answer (score 3):

relative to index.html I think that it should be : data="../../logs/log-file.txt". One less directory shift.

Answer (score -2):

Just change the .txt file to a .html file, and add styling... It works just fine, just add a linkto it in index.html.